# Is there a way to use UIView animations with custom ease equation

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, animation, uiview, uikit

`UIView` provides a few easing options (`UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn`, `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut`, `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut`) for its animation, but I want more control over the easing.

Is there a way to provide it a custom equation, or in any way get more control over it? That is, aside from using `touchesBegan:` etc. to roll my own animations.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to use core animation for this.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Using CAKeyframeAnimation ( http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CAKeyframeAnimation ) you can customize the timing of an animaiton